# rotate3d shorthand

Tags: css, css-transforms

How to combine `rotateX(50deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(15deg)` in shorthand `rotate3d()`?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

`rotateX(50deg)` is equivalent to `rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 50deg)`

`rotateY(20deg)` is equivalent to `rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg)`

`rotateZ(15deg)` is equivalent to `rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg)`

So...

`rotateX(50deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(15deg)`

is equivalent to

`rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 50deg) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 20deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg)`

---

For a generic `rotate3d(x, y, z, α)`, you have the matrix

[image: generic rotate matrix]

where

[image: explanation]

---

You now get the matrices for each of the 3 `rotate3d` transforms and you multiply them. And the resulting matrix is the matrix corresponding to the resulting single `rotate3d`. Not sure how to easy it is to extract the values for `rotate3d` out of it, but it's sure easy to extract those for a single `matrix3d`.

---

In the first case (`rotateX(50deg)` or `rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 50deg)`), you have:

`x = 1`, `y = 0`, `z = 0`, `α = 50deg`

So the first row of the matrix in this case is `1 0 0 0`.

The second one is `0 cos(50deg) -sin(50deg) 0`.

The third one `0 sin(50deg) cos(50deg) 0`.

And the fourth one is obviously `0 0 0 1`.

---

In the second case, you have `x = 0`, `y = 1`, `z = 0`, `α = 20deg`.

First row: `cos(20deg) 0 sin(20deg) 0`.

Second row: `0 1 0 0`.

Third row: `-sin(20) 0 cos(20deg) 0`.

Fourth: `0 0 0 1`

---

In the third case, you have `x = 0`, `y = 0`, `z = 1`, `α = 15deg`.

First row: `cos(15deg) -sin(15deg) 0 0`.

Second row `sin(15deg) cos(15deg) 0 0`.

And the third and the fourth row are `0 0 1 0` and `0 0 0 1` respectively.

---

***Note***: you may have noticed that the signs of the sin values for the rotateY transform are different than for the other two transforms. It's not a computation mistake. The reason for this is that, for the screen, you have the y-axis pointing down, not up.

---

So these are the three `4x4` matrices that you need to multiply in order to get the `4x4` matrix for the resulting single `rotate3d` transform. As I've said, I'm not sure how easy it can be to get the 4 values out, but the 16 elements in the 4x4 matrix are exactly the 16 parameters of the `matrix3d` equivalent of the chained transform.

---

**EDIT**:

Actually, it turns out it's pretty easy... You compute the trace (sum of diagonal elements) of the matrix for the `rotate3d` matrix.

`4 - 2*2*(1 - cos(α))/2 = 4 - 2*(1 - cos(α)) = 2 + 2*cos(α)`

You then compute the trace for the product of the three `4x4` matrices, you equate the result with `2 + 2*cos(α)` you extract `α`. Then you compute `x`, `y`, `z`.

In this particular case, if I computed correctly, the trace of the matrix resulting from the product of the three `4x4` matrices is going to be:

```
T = 
cos(20deg)*cos(15deg) + 
cos(50deg)*cos(15deg) - sin(50deg)*sin(20deg)*cos(15deg) + 
cos(50deg)*cos(20deg) + 
1
```

So `cos(α) = (T - 2)/2 = T/2 - 1`, which means that `α = acos(T/2 - 1)`.

Comment: yeah I don't even know how to fact check that. I was totally going to until I saw the sin. cause it opened up my mind. when i saw the sin. shoutout ace of base

Comment: Note that the rotate matrix is applicable only if the `[x,y,z]` vector  is normalized, that is, only if vector length `Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)` is one. If it is not normalized, it can easily be converted into a normalized one, by diving each `x`, `y` and `z` by their length.

Comment: You must be holding a Master of Fine Arts in Mathematic. Thanks for this poem, Ana!

Comment: @Andrew: don't worry, sin gets the better of many of us...sigh.

Comment: Epic great complete answer for this! I couldn't ask for more, thanks a lot for this.

Comment: What about getting the rotate3d value from the matrix (which seems to be a single row one) returned by jquery `css` method? `matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.642788, -0.766044, 0, 0, 0.766044, 0.642788, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)` https://jsfiddle.net/k35o1s27/1/

Comment: @Alvaro It's not one row. The first 4 values (`1 0 0 0`) are the values on the 1st column, the next 4 (`0, .642788, -.766044, 0`) are the values on the 2nd column and so on. Here, the values you have fit the `rotateX` situation in my answer above. `.64` is the `cos` of your angle, `-.76` is the `sin`. These signs place it between `-90°` and `0°`. You can get the exact value with `α = Math.atan2(-.76, .64)`. Then you have `rotate3d(1, 0, 0, αrad)`. Or you could convert `α` to degrees: `α *= 180/Math.PI`

Comment: @Ana yeap, that's right. But [I ended finding out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39870758/1081396) it is not possible to get the exact value, but a relative one. Btw, crazy conferences you do!

Comment: MDN says: "Unlike rotations in the 2D plane, the composition of 3D rotations is usually not commutative. In other words, the order in which the rotations are applied impacts the result."
Does that mean that there are 3D rotations that cannot be specified by rotate3d? It seems from this answer and other documentation that rotate3d rotates in order of x then y then z.  But I can't find an example where the order of dimensions matters.

Comment: @Ana does it mean that the expected shorthand is `rotate3d(1,1,1,acos(T/2 - 1))` in this particular case? I'm also curious to what happens with values like `rotateX(180deg)` =)

Comment: How do I remove the rotation for the child of a parent which has a rotation applied? Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/L9nefum0/1/ The blue box is a reference box. I want to reset the rotation for the red box.

Answer (score 15):

Syntax:

```
rotate3d(x, y, z, a)
```

Values:

- `x`
  Is a `<number>` describing the x-coordinate of the vector denoting the axis of rotation.
- `y`
  Is a `<number>` describing the y-coordinate of the vector denoting the axis of rotation.
- `z`
  Is a `<number>` describing the z-coordinate of the vector denoting the axis of rotation.
- `a`
  Is an `<angle>` representing the angle of the rotation. A positive angle denotes a clockwise rotation, a negative angle a counter-clockwise one.

Like in :

```
.will-distort{
    transform:rotate3d(10, 10, 10, 45deg);
}
```

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/wvYKZ/)

[Caniuse it here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)

[More docs about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property)

Comment: Maybe I'm thick, but I think he's asking for an algorithm to go from the chained transform to a single `rotate3d`, not for the definition of `rotate3d`.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to combine rotateX(50deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(15deg) in shorthand rotate3d() in CSS

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what you are trying to do, this 'hack' could help you. Let's say you are doing animation, and you want add transformation after transformation and so on, and you don't want the CSS to look like it's doing 100's of transformations:

This works in chrome:
 1. Apply whatever transform you want to an element. 
 2. Next time you want to add a transform, add it to the computed transform:
    "window.getComputedStyle(element).transform" - but make sure to put the new transform to the left.
 3. Now your transform would look like "rotateZ(30deg) matrix3d(......).
 4. Next time you want to add another transform, repeat the process - Chrome always reduces the transforms to matrix3d notation.

TL;DR- apply whatever transforms you want, and then get the computed matrix3d transformation.

This trick also lets you quickly (that is, without doing any math by yourself) make a functionality that rotates an object with respect to your reference frame in any direction. See the sample below:

**EDIT**: I have added xyz translations as well. Using this, it would be very easy to place objects in specific 3d locations with specific orientations in mind. Or...imagine a cube that bounces and changes it's spin axis with each bounce depending on how it lands!

```js
 var boxContainer = document.querySelector('.translator'),
     cube = document.getElementById('cube'),
     optionsContainer = document.getElementById('options');
 var dims = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
 var currentTransform;
 var currentTranslate;
 var init = function () {
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.xRotation input')
         .addEventListener('input', function (event) {
         if (currentTransform != 'none') {
             var newTransform = 'rotateX(' + (360 - event.target.value) + 'deg) ' + currentTransform;
         } else {
             var newTransform = 'rotateX(' + (360 - event.target.value) + 'deg)';
         }
         cube.style.transform = newTransform;
     }, false);

     optionsContainer.querySelector('.yRotation input')
         .addEventListener('input', function (event) {
         if (currentTransform != 'none') {
             var newTransform = 'rotateY(' + (360 - event.target.value) + 'deg) ' + currentTransform;
         } else {
             var newTransform = 'rotateY(' + (360 - event.target.value) + 'deg)';
         }
         cube.style.transform = newTransform;
     }, false);

     optionsContainer.querySelector('.zRotation input')
         .addEventListener('input', function (event) {

         if (currentTransform != 'none') {
             var newTransform = 'rotateZ(' + (360 - event.target.value) + 'deg) ' + currentTransform;
         } else {
             var newTransform = 'rotateZ(' + (360 - event.target.value) + 'deg)';
         }
         cube.style.transform = newTransform;
     }, false);

     optionsContainer.querySelector('.xTranslation input')
         .addEventListener('input', function (event) {

         if (currentTranslate != 'none') {
             var newTransform = 'translateX(' + (100 - event.target.value) + 'px) ' + currentTranslate;
         } else {
             var newTransform = 'translateX(' + (100 - event.target.value) + 'px)';
         }
         boxContainer.style.transform = newTransform;
     }, false);

     optionsContainer.querySelector('.yTranslation input')
         .addEventListener('input', function (event) {

         if (currentTranslate != 'none') {
             var newTransform = 'translateY(' + (100 - event.target.value) + 'px) ' + currentTranslate;
         } else {
             var newTransform = 'translateY(' + (100 - event.target.value) + 'px)';
         }
         boxContainer.style.transform = newTransform;
     }, false);
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.zTranslation input')
         .addEventListener('input', function (event) {

         if (currentTranslate != 'none') {
             var newTransform = 'translateZ(' + (500 - event.target.value) + 'px) ' + currentTranslate;
         } else {
             var newTransform = 'translateZ(' + (500 - event.target.value) + 'px)';
         }
         boxContainer.style.transform = newTransform;
     }, false);



reset();

 };

 function reset() {
     currentTransform = window.getComputedStyle(cube).transform;
     currentTranslate = window.getComputedStyle(boxContainer).transform;
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.xRotation input').value = 360;
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.yRotation input').value = 360;
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.zRotation input').value = 360;
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.xTranslation input').value = 100;
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.yTranslation input').value = 100;
     optionsContainer.querySelector('.zTranslation input').value = 500;


 }


 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
 document.addEventListener('mouseup', reset, false);
```

```css
.translator
{
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.threeSpace
{
 height: 200px;
 moz-perspective: 1200px;
 o-perspective: 1200px;
 perspective: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 transform-origin: 50px 50px 100px;
 webkit-perspective: 1200px;
 width: 100px;
    perspective-origin: 100px 25px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#pointer{
    position:relative;
    height:2px;
    width:2px;
    top:25px;
    left:100px;
    background:blue;
    z-index:9999;
    
}



#cube
{
 height: 100%;
 moz-transform-origin: 90px 110px 0px;
 moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 o-transform-origin: 90px 110px 0px;
 o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 position: absolute;
 transform-origin: 90px 110px 0px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 webkit-transform-origin: 90px 110px 0px;
 webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 width: 100%;
}
#cube .midPoint{
    position:absolute;
    top:48px;
    left:48px;
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    background:green;
}

#cube figure
{
 border: 2px solid black;
 color: white;
 display: block;
 font-size: 60px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 96px;
 line-height: 96px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 width: 96px;
    /* transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}
#cube .front
{
 background: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
}

#cube .back
{
 background: hsl(60, 100%, 50%);
}
#cube .right
{
 background: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);
}
#cube .left
{
 background: hsl(180, 100%, 50%);
}
#cube .top
{
 background: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
}
#cube .bottom
{
 background: hsl(300, 100%, 50%);
}
#cube .front
{
 moz-transform: translateZ(50px);
 o-transform: translateZ(50px);
 transform: translateZ(50px);
 webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
}



#cube .back
{
 moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(50px);
 o-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(50px);
 transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(50px);
 webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(50px);
}
#cube .right
{
 moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
 o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
 webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
#cube .left
{
 moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
 o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
 webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
#cube .top
{
 moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
 o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
 webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
#cube .bottom
{
 moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
 o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
 webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}
#options{
    position:absolute;
    width:80%;
    top:40%;
    
    
}
#options input
{
 width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
     <div class="threeSpace">
         <div id="pointer"></div>
    <div class="translator">
        <div id="cube">
            <figure class="front"><div class='midPoint'></div></figure>
            <figure class="back"></figure>
            <figure class="right"></figure>
            <figure class="left"></figure>
            <figure class="top"></figure>
            <figure class="bottom"></figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <section id="options">
        <p class="xRotation">
            <label>xRotation</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="720" value="360" data-units="deg" />
        </p>
        <p class="yRotation">
            <label>yRotation</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="720" value="360" data-units="deg" />
        </p>
        <p class="zRotation">
            <label>zRotation</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="720" value="360" data-units="deg" />
        </p>
        <p class="xTranslation">
            <label>xTranslation</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" data-units="deg" />
        </p>
        <p class="yTranslation">
            <label>yTranslation</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100" data-units="deg" />
        </p>
        <p class="zTranslation">
            <label>zTranslation</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="500" data-units="deg" />
        </p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This is one of the most useful posts ever, thnak you

Answer (score 3):

The exact value is `rotate3d(133,32,58,58deg)`

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qqe7j/) (For chrome and Safari, using -webkit-transform)

Comment: **How exactly** do you compute it?

Comment: @Ana I don't, that's why your answer is 10x better :)