# Mouse controlled first person movement JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement a first person movement using the mouse.
I do have it working with keyboard yet I'm having difficulties implementing it using mouse since movement to a specific side isn't that clear (i.e moving left can include moving up or down).
I want to use the `matrix3d` in order to receive changed values of the position.

**EDIT #2** Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WQeHb/).

**EDIT** I've pasted the new code I've managed to resolve:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var MOVE = 10; // how much to move
        var XTURN = 1; // how much to rotate
        var YTURN = 1; // how much to rotate
        var transformer, origMat, translationMatrix, result;
        transformer = document.getElementById("transformer");

        if ($.browser.webkit)
            origMat = new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(transformer).webkitTransform);

        //turn left
        if (e.pageX < xPrev) {
            if (XTURN < 0) {
                XTURN *= -1;
            }
            xPrev = e.pageX;
        //turn right
        } else {
            if (XTURN > 0) {
                XTURN *= -1;
            }
            xPrev = e.pageX;

        }
        //look up
        if (e.pageY < yPrev) {
            if (YTURN < 0) {
                YTURN *= -1;
            } 
            yPrev = e.pageY;
        //look down
        } else {
            if (YTURN > 0) {
                YTURN *= -1;
            }
            yPrev = e.pageY;
        }

        translationMatrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix("matrix3d(" + cos(XTURN).toFixed(10) + ",0," + sin(XTURN).toFixed(10) + ",0,0,"+ cos(-YTURN).toFixed(10) +","+ sin(YTURN).toFixed(10) +",0, " + sin(-XTURN).toFixed(10) + ","+ sin(-YTURN).toFixed(10) +"," + cos(XTURN).toFixed(10) + ",0,0,0,0,1)");

        transformer.style.webkitTransform = translationMatrix.multiply(origMat).toString();
    });
```

As you can see (Sorry for the one line matrix) I'm stating the changes of the X and Y rotations on the same matrix change and then committing it, the issue now is with the `cos(XTURN).toFixed(10)` which can be related to the X and Y rotations, so you can see it works but not perfect.
Would appreciate any tips/ideas.

P.S I don't want to use the [Pointer Lock API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/), even though it's great, since I want it to support maximal number of browsers.

Comment: If you have it working, please post what you change in an answer, or delete the question (the answer would be better).

Comment: It's not working as it should be therefore it is not resolved so posting an answer to it would be the wrong thing to do. I've posted an edit of what have changed since my first question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought you said you resolved it.

Comment: Did you had a look at [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) ? I could try to find some of my old code using this technic if you are interrested. Those are really easier to manipulate with less computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JavaScript is mostly better than libraries (unless it's a "*Code less do more*" thing),
since you can understand what your code really does.

This is my entire JavaScript code:

```
var velocity = 0.5;

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var angleX = e.pageY * velocity * Math.PI / 180;
    var angleY = e.pageX * velocity * Math.PI / 180;
    document.getElementById('transformer').style.webkitTransform = 'matrix3d(' + Math.cos(-angleY) + ',0,' + Math.sin(-angleY) + ',0,' + (Math.sin(angleX)*Math.sin(-angleY)) + ',' + Math.cos(angleX) + ',' + (-Math.sin(angleX)*Math.cos(-angleY)) + ',0,' + (-Math.cos(angleX)*Math.sin(-angleY)) + ',' + Math.sin(angleX) + ',' + (Math.cos(angleX)*Math.cos(-angleY)) + ',0,0,0,0,1)';
};
```

And [this is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdvKy/).

It works!

**(I even made an example of this using the Pointer Lock API: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5KCv/)** (click the square to begin)

---

Explanation:

First, a velocity variable to easily set the rotation speed.
Then, a `mousemove` event which has the two rotation variabls set.
The last line is to convert from `rotateX` and `rotateY` transformations, to `matrix3d` as requested.
[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207351/rotate3d-in-css3) helped me get to the following solution.

---

`rotateX(angleX)` is equal to the following matrix:

```
1               0               0               0


0               cos(angleX)     -sin(angleX)    0


0               sin(angleX)     cos(angleX)     0


0               0               0               1
```

`rotateY(angleY)` is equal to the following matrix:

```
cos(angleY)     0               sin(angleY)     0


0               1               0               0


-sin(angleY)    0               cos(angleY)     0


0               0               0               1
```

And to use them both together, you need to multiply the two matrices.
So I wrote a small JavaScript tool to give me the calculation I need to do to get the result of this multiplication.

The result:

```
cos(angleY)               sin(angleX)*sin(angleY)   cos(angleX)*sin(angleY)   0



0                         cos(angleX)               -sin(angleX)              0



-sin(angleY)              sin(angleX)*cos(angleY)   cos(angleX)*cos(angleY)   0



0                         0                         0                         1
```

And that's the way to convert `rotateX` and `rotateY` to `matrix3d`.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is really great explanation, Made me decide this answer is the better one. (even though @IcanDivideBy0 had same answer yet less detailed). I wonder if usage of quaternions, as mentioned in other answers, contributes in a different way to the solution. (not just a nicer code)

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite clear to me what your high level goal is. It sounds like you're trying to implement a Counterstrike-like game in JS and CSS. Which is awesome! For the rest of this answer, I'm going to assume that you are trying to do something like that.

Realistically, you *must* use the Pointer Lock API. Otherwise, you won't be able to turn around by only moving the mouse left. You'll hit the edge of the browser window and stop turning. The browser support isn't great, but it's by far a better experience for the gamer!

In order to render your world with CSS transforms, you need to do a complicated series of transforms to generate the matrix for every side of every object visible in the game world. This is because the browser's perspective is always looking directly along the Z axis. So in order to animate things "around" the viewer's eye, you have to translate and rotate them around. After a bit of poking around, I came to the conclusion that doing all the transforms in CSS is prohibitively slow (and complicated!). But never fear, there's another way! WebGL or Canvas to the rescue!

Take a look at Isaac Sukin's game [Nemesis](http://icecreamyou.github.io/Nemesis/). It's an excellent example, and he's written a [tutorial](http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2012/06/how-build-first-person-shooter-browser-threejs-and-webglhtml5-canvas) to come up with something similar! The library it's based on, Three.js, is very widely used and has a very understandable API. It takes almost all of the hard part out, and lets you just make a 3D world!

Good luck with the game!

Comment: The game [Nemsis](http://icecreamyou.github.io/Nemesis/) you linked isn’t too hard to control even though it doesn’t have pointer lock. You turn your character not with mouse movement but with mouse deviation from the center of the window. So when the mouse is on the left side of the screen, you keep on turning left. You also shoot where the pointer is instead of straight forward. Pointer Lock would be better, and it would be nice if Shahar’s game detected if Pointer Lock were supported and used it if so, but I wouldn’t call it *required*.

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer yet it does not really resolve my issue, I'll explain: I'm able to achieve X rotation and Y rotation separately using the mouse movement, same as the Nemesis (only Y rotation there), Yet I want to be able and combine those 2 movements so the user will experience a FPS style looking around, moving on the Z axis will be done with keyboard so no problems there.
Regarding WebGL, it is amazing I do agree but not relevant for my specific project nor goal here and since the existing environment I have didn't created using Canvas this is not assisting me either.

Comment: Oh, okay. If all you want to do is rotate a view in both directions at the same time, should either do two transformations on the matrix3d(). or rotate once around <1,1,0> (or similar). Take a look at the [Mozilla documentation for `rotate3d()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#rotate3d()) and then use that matrix transformation instead of the one you have.

Comment: @tangphillip I do aware of the rotate3d() yet as you can see from my question I want to work with matrix3d since I want to plot the values after change, since I'm using them for other objects placed in the "world". In case there is a way to translate changed made using rotate3d to matrix3d values I will see it as a possible solution, yet I can't find a way to perform such conversion of values.

Comment: @ShaharGalukman As listed in the Mozilla docs, the matrix operation corresponding to rotate3d() is:

    1+(1-cos(a))(x^2-1)  // z*sin(a)+xy(1-cos(a)) // -y*sin(a)+xz(1-cos(a)) // 0 |||
    -z*sin(a)+xy(1-cos(a)) // 1+(1-cos(a))(y^2-1) // x*sin(a)+yz(1-cos(a)) // 0 |||
    y*sin(a) + xz(1-cos(a)) // -x*sin(a)+yz(1-cos(a)) // 1+(1-cos(a))(z^2-1) // 0 |||
    0 // 0 // 0 // 1

Comment: It is listed but look at the answer I accepted, the solution really use more clean and logical. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

Using quaternions is really easier. I found an implementation in [Google closure library](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/) so I made an example (also, check [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Q9T/1/)):

```
goog.require('goog.vec.Quaternion');

var velocity = 0.5;

var lastX = null;
var lastY = null;
var angleX = 0;
var angleY = 0;

$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (lastX == null) lastX = e.pageX;
    if (lastY == null) lastY = e.pageY;

    angleX += (e.pageX - lastX) * velocity * Math.PI / 180;
    angleY += (e.pageY - lastY) * velocity * Math.PI / 180;

    lastX = e.pageX;
    lastY = e.pageY;

    var quat = goog.vec.Quaternion.concat(
        goog.vec.Quaternion.fromAngleAxis(angleX, [0, 1, 0], []),
        goog.vec.Quaternion.fromAngleAxis(-angleY, [1, 0, 0], []), []);

    var matrix = goog.vec.Quaternion.toRotationMatrix4(quat, []);

    $("#transformer").css({
        webkitTransform: "matrix3d(" + matrix.join(",") + ")"
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't knew about this great library and the solution really elegant using it. Haven't put it to the test yet but it seems to solve the issue I was having trouble with and as a bonus I got to know this library. Could your further explain though the usage of Quaternion and how it resolves to the matrix3d, just to fully understand the code and math behind it, Thank you.