# How to convert from CSS `rotate3d()` to `rotateX() rotateY() rotateZ()`?

Tags: css, transform

I’m trying to figure out how to convert from a `rotate3d()` function to the equivalent `rotateX() rotateY() rotateZ()` functions.  It’s easy for vectors along the prime axes, but I’d like to know how to do it for arbitrary vectors.  I’m hopeless at matrix math, which I realize is probably a barrier here, but ideally, I’d like to end up with something like:

- Given `rotate3d(x,y,z,a)`…
- …the value of `rotateX()` is determined with [[ *as-simple-as-possible equation here* ]]
- …the value of `rotateY()` is determined with [[ *as-simple-as-possible equation here* ]]
- …the value of `rotateZ()` is determined with [[ *as-simple-as-possible equation here* ]]

Having those would be highly useful for constructing visualization tools to help teach authors how `rotate3d()` works, which is part of my end goal here.

(This question is basically the inverse [or is it converse?] of [rotate3d shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207351/rotate3d-shorthand).)

Comment: The question you linked shows the equivalencies.

Comment: But not in any way I understand, so extrapolating how to reverse what was done is doubly difficult.  A little help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 50deg)` is equivalent to `rotateX(50deg)`, etc. etc.

Comment: Okay, that I got because it’s the simplest possible case, but how does one turn `rotate3d(-0.95,0.5,1,45deg)` into `rotateX() rotateY() rotateZ()` equivalents?

Comment: Do the same thing for each... `rotateX(-.95*45 deg)`

Comment: That doesn’t actually work.  As an example, `rotate3d(1,1,0,45edg)` is _not_ the same as `rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0)`.  See http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/rotate3d-explore.html as an example.

Comment: I think you're doomed here. You want a "simple" conversion but there isn't one. And even if we came up with formulas, I'm not sure that it would help "authors" visualize what's happening. You're trying to build a tool that "simplifies" things for other people but you don't seem to understand the technology yourself.

Comment: Of course I don’t understand it.  Otherwise, I wouldn’t have had to ask the question.  I’m pretty sure being helped to understand that which is not understood is the whole point of StackOverflow.

Comment: @EricA.Meyer First of all a simple question, do you know that matrix operation are not commutative? i.e. the product rotateX() . rotateY() . rotateZ() is different from the product rotateZ() . rotateY() . rotateX(). Another point is that when you apply a rotation also the initial X, Y and Z axes are changed, this is the reason because it's difficult to describe the relation. however mathematically I think the relation you want is this described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_.E2.86.94_Euler_angles)

Comment: So is it possible to turn `rotate3d(-0.95,0.5,1,45deg)` into `rotateX() rotateY() rotateZ()`? Can someone edit the CSS on the [test page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/rotate3d-explore.html) to make the left and the right images identical?

Comment: Thanks, gipi!  I did know the first part, but your leadin to the Wikipedia reference caused me to look at it from another angle (pun intended) and I may have made a small step toward understanding.  So I hope, anyway.

Comment: I found these links: [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html) that shows one representation of a generic rotation using 3 rotations and [this](https://dev.opera.com/articles/w3c-device-orientation-usage/) where the author does things with matrix calculation for Device Orientation.