# Extract value from rotate3D

Tags: css, transform

How could i extract `rotateX rotateY rotateZ` from `rotate3d` shorthand CSS Property?

Example: `rotate3d(133,32,58,58deg)`

Comment: To clarify, this question is the inverse of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207351/rotate3d-shorthand