# Issue in transform property in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to rotate a div which is inside another div. whats wrong with my code.I come across with another method(:before child) but  whats wrong with this methods? Thanks

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}
.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.effect2 {
  position: relative;
}
.box1 {
  transform: rotate3d;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have no rotate values stated.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Talks/2012/0416-CSS-WWW2012/Demos/transforms/demo-rotate3d.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207351/rotate3d-shorthand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give x,y or z to rotate and add the value

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}
.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.effect2 {
  position: relative;
}
.box1 {
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Here are some posible values

```
transform: rotate3d(1, 2.0, 3.0, 10deg)
transform: rotateX(10deg)
transform: rotateY(10deg)
transform: rotateZ(10deg)
```

[SOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}
.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.effect2 {
  position: relative;
}
.box1{
    transition: 1.5s;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.box1:hover{
          transform: rotate3d(1,-1, 1,60deg);
       }
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

rotate3d, where supported, needs parameters, example:

```
transform: rotate3d(1, 2.0, 3.0, 10deg)
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}
.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.effect2 {
  position: relative;
}
.box1 {
  transform: rotate3d(1,2.0,3.0,90deg);
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="box effect2">
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt to different browsers.

```
.class {

-webkit-transform:rotate(deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(deg);
     -o-transform:rotate(deg);
        transform:rotate(deg);
}
```