# Flip a triangle 3d css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to have a right angle triangle such as this

```
. . . . . . .
.         .
.       .
.     .
.   .
. .
.
```

flip with a 3d animation to become a right angle such as this

```
            .
          . .
        .   .
      .     .
    .       .
  .         .
. . . . . . .
```

I have had very little luck with diagonal transformation, yet alone one of a triangle.  I was able to flip it vertically and horizontally following the guides here http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip however I cannot flip the box diagonally.

Any help or direction is most appreciated!

as requested JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y36cdwx2/

Comment: please add a fiddle of what you've achieved so far.

Comment: Do a jsFiddle with your code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand more about css3 rotate3d, you can visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207351/rotate3d-shorthand) to learn more about it.
To accomplish what you want to do to rotate your box diagonally, you can use: `transform: rotate3d(90, -90, 0, 180deg);`

Here is the full source code how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/yp6j5qem/15

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to modify your code to make it a triangle and then have the triangle flip, but it breaks the entire functionality when I I convert the box to triangle, here is the source code, do you know if its possible to achieve this with triangle divs?  http://jsfiddle.net/yp6j5qem/11/

Comment: Here is the modified code that flips triangle: http://jsfiddle.net/yp6j5qem/15/
Hope this helps!

Comment: can't thank you enough!  If you don't mind, please update your answer with the latest fiddle as that one completely answers my question; so that future venturers can find the answer easier!